process.stdin is not recognized as ReadableStream when using readline.createInterface
I've got a strange issue with TypeScript when trying to use the readline to create an interface reading the console window. From what I can tell, process.stdin returns a ReadStream whilst createInterface is expecting a ReadableStream but I'm not sure how to convert them. When I try to create an interface with readline.createInterface, TypeScript throws the following error:
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(input: ReadableStream, output?: WritableStream | undefined, completer?: Completer | AsyncCompleter | undefined, terminal?: boolean | undefined): Interface', gave the following error.
    Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'input' does not exist in type 'ReadableStream'.

import * as readline from 'readline';

const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
    prompt: "> "
});

rl.on('line', (line) => {
    console.log(`got ${line}`);
    rl.prompt();
});

rl.prompt();

TypeScript Version: 5.2.2
Node.js Version: 18.20.4
@types/node Version: 22.5.2
I tried casting process.stdin to NodeJS.ReadableStream, made sure my tsconfig.json was set to expect node, but the same issue occurs. I've even tried updating @types/node to see if it's something to do with that to no avail. Any help would be amazing!

process.stdin instanceof stream.Readable is true. But you are using the other overload createInterface(options: ReadLineOptions): Interface, and I wonder why this does not show up in the error message.

@HeikoTheißen oh I see, sorry, how do I swap the overload, I’m rather new to TS

TS should find the right overload automatically. Don't know why this does not work here.
